# How to block/protect direct access via url?

Tags: .htaccess, access-control

I've been looking for days on how to block/protect pages from direct access via url, but nothing helped.

**Here's an example:** This **[page](http://pwtalk.net/cgi-bin/protect.cgi)** is protected or blocked from direct access. I was able to view the page via the home page `index.html` but if I copy&paste the url to access it directly, I can't view it.

---

- **Here's what I want:**
- I want to block or protect folders/html pages/files from direct access, either by redirecting to the home page `index.html` or by sending a 404 status code when the directory/page/file is directly accessed via url.
- I prefer protecting folders/html pages/files when directly accessed by sending a 404 status code or redirecting to my `notfound.html` 404 error page, if not possible, redirecting to home page.
- I don't mind using php or anything else, but I want to leave all my pages `.html`

---

- **What I want to block/protect from direct access:**
- `http://mywebsite.com/pages` the whole folder & all the `.html` pages
  that are in the folder.
- `http://mywebsite.com/images` the whole folder & all the images in the folder. (.png, .ico, .jpg).

---

*I don't want to simply just redirect pages, because source page can be viewed.*

I really need help with this, please be clear on how to... I'm currently learning all this stuff.

Comment: when there is no `HTTP_REFERER`, `document.referrer` attribute, the request possibly is a *direct hit*. You cannot safely distinct between direct and non-direct hits.

Comment: This is a hard problem. The most straight-forward solution is often a login system

Comment: @DanFromGermany How can I do that? anything helps, All I want is to block direct access.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I don't need a login system, I just want to block a simple page that contains a video which is used in `index.html` but I don't want it to be viewed by direct access via url.

Comment: See the duplicate link; also http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1694/Prevent+hotlinking+with+a+.htaccess+file for a purely .htaccess based solution

Comment: Also here is a nice writeup http://www.hardanswers.net/hotlink-protection

Comment: @Pekka웃 I uploaded my work on a temporary host, here's exactly what I want.
I'm using this [PAGE](http://ahwanas.site88.net/pages/raw.html) which is `http://ahwanas.site88.net/pages/raw.html` on this [PAGE](http://ahwanas.site88.net/) which is `index.html`

I want to block direct access to `raw.html` but still be able to use it in `index.html` when I click on "raw".

Comment: @Pekka웃 Thank you, I will read that.

Answer (score 2):

When there is no `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` (PHP), `document.referrer` (JavaScript) attribute, the request possibly is a *direct hit*.

You **cannot** safely distinct between direct and non-direct hits. For example, the HTTP referrer is a header and can easily be changed by the client (user).

Also, some **domain policies** and **secured browsers** > enforce removal < of the referer by default. That means, you might run into **blocking legit requests**!

If you intend to do it, the simplest case in PHP is:

```
<?php
if (empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
    header('Location: /');
    exit;
}
```

There are similiar solutions for your webserver (Apache .htaccess):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !=""
RewriteRule - [F]
```

*(not tested!)*